# Matching a templated string in RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to put together a small demonstration that uses client-side templating for a short talk. My regexp dynamically gets created and aims to replace instances of itself within a string, but it's not working for some odd reason, I've console logged the vital parts, can anyone advise?

My HTML:

```
<script type="text/template" id="link">
  <a href="{href}">
    {title}
  </a>
</script>
```

And my JavaScript in a jsFiddle and below:

```
var linkTemplate = document.querySelector('#link').innerHTML.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');

var data = [{
"title": "Google",
"href": "//google.com"
},{
"title": "Yahoo",
"href": "//yahoo.com"
}];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
var obj = data[i];
for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var regexp = new RegExp('\{' + key + '\}', 'i');
        console.log(regexp);
        linkTemplate.replace(regexp, 'l');
        console.log(obj[key]);
    }
}
document.body.innerHTML += linkTemplate;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K9z6C/

Comment: It's really not that much code... perhaps you could just place the JS code in your post?

Comment: the replace functions does not mutate the string it's called on as you seem to expect. It returns a new string with the result

Comment: Interesting, Hugo, would it take much more to get it to replace all instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your query correctly, you need to make the below change:

```
linkTemplate = linkTemplate.replace(regexp, 'l');
```

Reason - `.replace()` returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement.

**EDIT:** Updated based on sample fiddle you had posted in MC ND's answer. Updated code is as below:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var obj = data[i];
    link = linkTemplate; //set the temporary variable with the template script for every data item
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var regexp = new RegExp('\{' + key + '\}', 'g');
            link = link.replace(regexp, obj[key]); //replace the href and title based on data
        }
    }
    document.body.innerHTML += link + '<br/>'; //add the value from the temporary variable to document body.
}
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/K9z6C/7/)

Comment: Thanks very much, totally makes sense now. Grab it before it enters the second loop, then replace for each prop.

Answer (score 0):

You can also reverse the login and match all `{...}` and then try to fetch the data:

```
var str = 'hello {name}, you are {age} years old',
    tpl = function(str, data) {
        return str.replace(/\{(.*?)\}/g, function(_, a) { return data[a]; });
    };

tpl(str, {name: 'John', age: 47}); // Hello John, you are 47 years old
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have replaced content in linkTemplate for the first data, you have no more placeholders to replace for the second set of data. Save to a temporary sting to add to result.

Comment: Thanks, it's nearly working. It's not replacing instances globally though, it replaces just the hyperlinks so far: http://jsfiddle.net/K9z6C/2/